# Google Tag Manager tag not triggered despite DataLayer push being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Strictly following https://www.rheinwunder.com/blog/analytics-conversion-funnel-ajax-gtm/ tutorial, I have setup GA Destination Goal using dataLayer and Virtual Pageviews through Google Tag Manager. dataLayer.push-es do occur, yet, only one of my tags is actually firing. I have set all tags and triggers in the same fashion and checked over and over again. So, I get tag fired for '/signup-confirm' virtual URL, while for '/signup-step-1', '/signup-step-2', the tags are not firing.

My datalayer handling code looks like this (every dataLayer.push is set to some button's onclick() function):

```
dataLayer.push({'event':'signup', 'virtualPageURL':'/signup-confirm', 'virtualPageTitle' : 'Signup confirm'});

dataLayer.push({'event':'signup', 'virtualPageURL':'/signup-step-2', 'virtualPageTitle' : 'Signup - Step 2'});
```

As I previously said, the tags and the triggers are set in the same fashion and doublechecked. I can't really tell what's going on? Just see no differences.

Image of dataLayer push being pushed - yet no Tag is triggered ( in Tags tab - not seen in picture):

[image: dataLayer push]

jQuery library is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you're referring to suggest that you have a Custom event Trigger for 'signup' event and you're using this trigger to fire the Google Analytics Tag.
I'd suggest you to double-check the trigger configuration. You can also switch to 'Tags' tab in GTM debug panel to check what particular triggers work for your Analytics Tag.

Comment: Man, I love you. Saved my day. I thought everything was OK with my Triggers, but I had a tiny typo. Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaankkkkkkkkksssssssss!!!